# Removing index.php of codeigniter on local

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove index.php,in my localhost, but it seems doesn't working,its on `http://localhost/testing`.

I put .htacces in 'testing' directory under the htdocs.

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
 at Apache/conf also already unchecked.

Here my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /testing/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Here my config:

```
$config['base_url']    = "http://localhost/testing";
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

When I access login controller, it's not found.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /testing/login was not found on this server.

I really don't know what to try next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there any others settings ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

Config.php :-

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/testing/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

basically the index.php is included in all URLs:

we can remove this using .htaccess with a simple rules. following is  an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected,

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /testing/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

now restart your server and check

Answer (score 0):

Your `htaccess` should be like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

There's no need to append `/testing/` since `RewriteBase` already takes care of that.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? Change the flags to `[R,L]` to see if browser gets redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the trailing slash in `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

`$config['base_url']` should be `http://localhost/testing/`

`$config['index_page']` should be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|resources)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /mainpage
```

your config file is fine

Difference being the "?" after index.php

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try changing the value of `$config[‘uri_protocol’]` in ./application/config/config.php. Sometimes CodeIgniter gets it wrong. Changing it to `PATH_INFO`might work.